# regarding one code segment in computing log_sum_exp

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

In this [tutorial on using Pytorch to implement BiLSTM-CRF](http://seba1511.net/tutorials/beginner/nlp/advanced_tutorial.html), author implements the following function. In specific, I am not quite understand what does `max_score_broadcast = max_score.view(1, -1).expand(1, vec.size()[1])` try to do?, or which kind of math formula it corresponds to?

```
# Compute log sum exp in a numerically stable way for the forward algorithm
def log_sum_exp(vec):
    max_score = vec[0, argmax(vec)]
    max_score_broadcast = max_score.view(1, -1).expand(1, vec.size()[1])
    return max_score + \
        torch.log(torch.sum(torch.exp(vec - max_score_broadcast)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, it seems like `vec` has a shape of `(1, n)`.
Now we can follow the code line by line:

```py
max_score = vec[0, argmax(vec)]
```

Using `vec` in the location `0, argmax(v)` is just a fancy way of taking the maximal value of `vec`. So, `max_score` is (as the name suggests) the maximal value of `vec`.

```py
max_score_broadcast = max_score.view(1, -1).expand(1, vec.size()[1])
```

Next, we want to subtract `max_score` from each of the elements of `vec`. 
To do so the code creates a vector of the same `shape` as `vec` with all elements equal to `max_score`.
First, `max_score` is reshaped to have two dimensions using the [`view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) command, then the expanded 2d vector is "stretched" to have length `n` using the [`expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) command.

Finally, the log sum exp is computed robustly:

```py
 return max_score + \
        torch.log(torch.sum(torch.exp(vec - max_score_broadcast)))
```

The validity of this computation can be seen in this picture:
[image]

The rationale behind it is that `exp(x)` can "explode" for `x > 0`, therefore, for numerical stability, it is best to subtract the maximal value *before* taking `exp`.

---

As a side note, I think a slightly more elegant way to do the same computation, taking advantage of [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html), would be

```py
max_score, _ = vec.max(dim=1, keepdim=True)  # take max along second dimension
lse = max_score + torch.log(torch.sum(torch.exp(vec - max_score), dim=1))
return lse
```

Also note that log sum exp is already implemented by pytorch: [`torch.logsumexp`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.logsumexp).

Comment: really appreciate your detailed answer. By the way, the torch.logsumexp is doing the same thing as the implementation posted in the above, is that right? Thanks.

Comment: @user288609AFAIK yes, it implements a robust computation.